# Coordinate free derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation

I am studying Symplectic Geometry and I was wondering how one can compute Euler-Lagrange equation in a coordinate free manner. 
For instance, I know for the following Lagrangian $L(x,v)=\frac{1}{2}g_{x}(v,v)-V(x)$ the corresponding equation is $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=-\nabla V$, but it is a bit complicated to derive it in a coordinate system.

Comment: This is a topic in Hamiltonian dynamics, with canonical variables. Goldstein or Landau has a good discussion of it.